# Working with Bootstrap container one column should stretch to full width and touch right side of screen

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I am using bootstrap. I have two columns (col-lg-6) inside container. Left side has regular text. Right side column has an image. According to design requirement, image that is inside right side column should stretch and touch the right side of screen and should not be contained inside the column. I cant use image as background. Image should be there in column so that it takes proper height inside column but it should stretch to the end of screen (viewport) to the right. How can it be achieved?

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  ...text
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <img>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The layout provided as the example is quite symmetrical. Try adding `position: absolute`,`right:0` and `width:50vw` to the image then you can position your image accordingly

Comment: That does not work. Also I do not want to position absolute image. I want image to use its height to push column height to image height. Positioning will collapse the columns height to the text height at left side and image at right side will overlap the content below. Dont want to use manual height for columns also.